# How to investigate [execution reverted] error in internal transactions - Goerli etherscan

Tags: ethereum, uniswap, etherscan

Please refer to this 'Add Liquidity' transaction on Uniswap V2:

https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x46419e4c70ddfe7a1510e49c568f332e43dc6a29aeb794a46ac8dd95063caff2#internal

You will notice that one of the internal transaction errored and execution reverted but the overall transaction was successfully completed. Looking for ideas to investigate such errors.

I did code inspections to identify if there are any possible causes for revert. Also have a debug event in the transaction and is accessible in the link above

Comment: On further internet search - I was able to get the trace of this transaction but still not clear what's going on - the trace is below
https://ctxt.io/2/AACQQAKWFA

Comment: You can use on-chain debuggers like https://tenderly.co/ to debug transactions